# My CSS is my react app isn't working as expected

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working in this [code branch](https://github.com/RickAnderson-hub/address-book/tree/integrate-html). It's a simple contacts app written with React as a self-study exercise.

My current problem is that when I click my add contact button, the add contact form in my modal is not styled correctly.
I'm trying to style it to `modal-content` from `./css/addContactModal.module.css` which is called within `AddContactModal.js`.
[image]
Can someone advise me where I've gone wrong with respect to changing the modal form's CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Class .modal-content:**

The class is defined as **.modal-content** in the CSS styles, but in the React component, you're using .styles.modalContent instead.

Make sure to align them so that the styles are correctly applied to the React component.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change the className in your css file addContactModal.module.css line 11 from modal-content to modalContent.

Answer (score 1):

i have downloaded your code and it works well.
your code is correct and style is appled to the correct element.

you can add below css to  addContactModal.module.css

```
.modal input {
  background-color: red;
}
```

the screenshot here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Your snippet works but does not solve my problem :)